# Map DB tables to objects in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, macos, core-data, orm

So the problems goes as follows. I have a working database with all relational tables already created, and I need to do a **object-relational mapping** of that database into objects in the code, in such manner that I am afterwards able to do something like this:

```
User user = new User(data);
db.save(user);
```

In other words, I need a mapping of DB tables into code objects such that these objects in code can be interacted with the database - from the code.

What would be the best way to do so?

Comment: Is this a Core Data question?

Comment: @Willeke I am not sure whether Core Data can do that - can it? If so, then yes, it is a Core Data question.

Comment: You can't use Core Data with an existing database.

Comment: @Willeke So what should I use then? How to do that mapping?

Comment: It might help if you gave some kind of clue about what database system you're already using.

Comment: @TomHarrington I have a remote SQL database with a connection string to it. It is MS SQL server.